# Cannot boot as directed from thumbdrive

Tags: boot

I've downloaded the basic Ubuntu,opened it with FileOpen (as recommended) and tried to run it rebooting my PC. It will not automatically run from the thumbdrive (opens Windows) and it will not run when I deliberately choose the thumbdrive (opens nothing whatever). I've deleted the thumbdrive contents and reloaded it a couple of times, with and without choosing everything showing on FileOpen (I get the same files opened either way).
I really want to try Ubuntu, but simply cannot get it to run. Any suggestions to accomplish this would be appreciated. I'm not PC savvy, but willing to try.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I tried the Boot Menu (F12 during startup) and changing boot priority in my BIOS (Delete during startup).  Still would not boot from my USB.  I even completely wiped my hard drive, and it would not work.  I probably had some setting screwed up.  The bootable thumb drive worked perfectly on one PC, but I just could not get it to work on the other.

I ended up creating a boot DVD, and it worked perfect.  So if you are having trouble booting from a USB, maybe you should try the DVD route.  Just a suggestion.